# group_concat was cut when running a query on table

Tags: mysql, group-concat, sql-server-group-concat

I have a table that looks likes this:
[image]

and this table contains 343 rows.

I'm trying to run this query on it:

```
create table newTest2 
select function_name, service_name, min(concurrency), substring_index(group_concat(date order by concurrency ), ',',1) as minDate, 
 max(concurrency), substring_index(group_concat(date order by concurrency desc), ',',1) as maxDate , avg(concurrency)
        from conc_intermidate
        group by function_name,service_name;
```

and when I run the query it gives me the : "row 203 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()", I don't know why it's giving me this error. Please HELP! thanks...

Comment: Pure guess: group_concat has a limit of the lengh of the comma seperated list it created and at row 203 that limit was reached.

Comment: Posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208773/mysql-row-30153-was-cut-by-group-concat-error

Comment: BTW you create a table that contains multiple values in one column. That is a no-go.

Comment: @RobertRozas thanks a lot .. I used the last comment in that post. I just run 'SET group_concat_max_len=15000;' and it ran!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to RobertRozas for providing me with similar post [MySQL “Row 30153 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208773/mysql-row-30153-was-cut-by-group-concat-error)
I ran `SET group_concat_max_len=15000;` and the query ran perfectly.