# limitation in automatic pivot table creation

Tags: mysql

I have the following query to create a query that creates a pivot table.
If I execute `SELECT * FROM @sql` I get the text stored in `@sql`. (sorry for the redundancy...)

The problem is that although I have close to 200 entries in solar.sensors, I only get 16 displayed in the `@sql`.

Is there any limitation in the number of entries that can be concatenated into a variable (in this case `@sql`) ?

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = ', sensor_id,
      ' THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "',sensor_id,
      '"\n'
    )
  ) INTO @sql 
FROM solar.sensors;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM solar.agregated 
                   GROUP BY date');
```

The content of `@sql` is:

```
SELECT date, MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 20 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "20"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 21 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "21"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 81 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "81"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 82 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "82"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 150 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "150"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 151 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "151"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 152 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "152"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 154 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "154"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 159 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "159"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 160 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "160"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 164 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "164"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 165 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "165"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 166 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "166"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 167 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "167"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 168 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "168"
,MAX(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 169 THEN power ELSE 0 END) AS "169"
                  FROM solar.agregated /*This is a view*/
                   GROUP BY date
```

Comment: And how many *distinct* `sensor_id` values are present in `solar.sensors` table?

Comment: all  the `sensor_id` are different, since it is the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is answered here:
[group_concat was cut when running a query on table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278249/group-concat-was-cut-when-running-a-query-on-table)

basically there is a limit in the number of characters that can be concatenated.
One can modify such limit with this command:

```
SET group_concat_max_len=150000000; /*or a very high number*/
```